Classic ASP JScript Broken after Windows 11 24H2
I've just upgraded windows 11 to 24H2. I write JScript in Classic ASP running on IIS.
After upgrading none of my code works anymore. I get

Catastrophic Error

and then

Script Engine Exception" "A ScriptEngine threw exception 'C0000005' in 'IActiveScript::SetScriptState()' from 'CActiveScriptEngine::ReuseEngine()'.

I tried uninstalling VBScript and classic ASP from windows, but no joy.
I saw there was some updates regarding VBScript so I'm wondering if it's to do with that.

What would un-installing VBScript have to do with JScript?
